# Set user permissions per connection?

Tags: sql-server, user-permissions

Is it somehow possible to set the user permissions per **connection** in SQL-Server?

for example:

```
DENY insert ON all TO user
DENY update ON all TO user
DENY delete ON all TO user
```

So, suppose a user is connected as `sa` (* see EDIT) in my application, can I somehow change (and possibly restore) permissions at some point for this user (so for e.g. at that point he has a read-only access)?

**EDIT:** sorry for giving a wrong example. the user is NOT `sa` but other user with full access.

Comment: The `sa` is effectively "god mode" on SQL Server. you can't `DENY` the `sa` from doing anything; even if you give them a `DENY` permission `sa` > `all other permissions`. If you want to limit a person's permissions, create them a login and user with appropriate permissions. **Don't** give people access to the `sa` account; that should only ever be used by a system administrator when all other options are exhausted.

Comment: @Larnu, the `sa` was an example for a user with full access

Comment: Yes, and you can't lower the permissions of the `sa`, so don't let them conenct as it,.

Comment: @Larnu, can I lower the permission for other user (not `sa`) but per connection basis? (Sorry for giving the wrong information - the user is actually NOT `sa`)

Comment: No. If you want a connection to have different permissions, use a different login. Permissions are set at Login and User level, a connection does not have permissions. if you change the permission of a login/user while it is connected, it will immediately have those permissions (a new connection does not need to be made), thus if there were multiple connections it will effect all of them. There's nothing wrong with an application having access to different login's users for different tasks; in fact I would suggest it's quite common; it's simple permission segregation.

Comment: @Larnu, Thanks. You can post the comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, permissions aren't set at connection level, they are set at Login and User level.

If you have a connection, and you change the permissions of the login/user being used, those permissions will be applied immediately to that connection, and any others; thus a connection using the Login and User `AppUser` cannot have different permissions to another connection user the exact same Login and User.

If you need an application to have different permissions for different things, there's nothing wrong with creating multiple Logins and Users; each with their own permissions. You then control the Login the application uses my using different connection string, depending on the role needed. This is quite a common practice; for example you might have a different database for your application's security model, and thus a different login is used to make changes to that database.

Answer (score 0):

there are system stored procedures about security section and i guess that would be the only way since SQL gotta be secured.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/security-stored-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dropsrvrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
EXEC sp_dropsrvrolemember 'JackO', 'sysadmin';
```